# What is the HTTP method for an API that calls another API?

Tags: api, rest, api-design

I am writing a service where the client makes an API call to my service, and my service then augments the request payload, then passes it on to another service. For my API, what should the HTTP method be if it's not interacting with a database?

Answer (score 1):

> what should the HTTP method be

Key idea: the fact that your server communicates with another API, rather than a database, or a filesystem, is an *implementation detail*; details of your implementation are not supposed to be leaking into your messages.

Given that the incoming request has a message body; GET, HEAD, DELETE are all right out, because those methods have no defined semantics for a payload.

POST/PUT/PATCH are all possible.

Ideally, you would match the method token that you are using to talk to your back end.  This is essentially how a reverse proxy works.  You're just playing man in the middle, after all, so it shouldn't be too much of a surprise that the request semantics match.

They don't always, of course - and you might want to inject your own semantics if you find that the API you are calling has made poor method choices in its own design.

When in doubt, [it is okay to use POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post)

Answer (score 0):

One of the REST principles — namely, ‘Layered System’ constraint — implies that:

> each component cannot "see" beyond the immediate layer with which they are interacting

So you actually should not make any difference between ‘simple’ and ‘proxied’ API calls.